# can not install ubuntu along with windows 10 by usb?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this problem with ubuntu 20.04 dual boot.

First, I installed Win 10 and everything seemed ok. I prepared 100 Gb in my hard disk to install ubuntu.

Then, I made an usb to install ubuntu to my computer, seemed ok.

But my problem is, when I tried to installed ubuntu, it gave me this message :

```
Missing operating system
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key
```

So , I am very confusing because I do not know what happening with this problem.
Could you please give me some ideas to solve this problem ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it was the way it was formatted.  You have to use Unetbootin or rufus.  There's another one called Balenetcher.  It was just way it was formated.  Ive had that happen to me pleny of times on my USB.  I just reformmated it again with another rog